# Cant create tables in mysql because they all depend on each other?

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table Supplier that has foreign key RepID, and another called Rep that has foreign key SupplierID. How do I get around this? If I disable foreign key checking I get an error saying a foreign key constraint fails when trying to add data:

```
INSERT INTO Supplier VALUES
    (44, "PENCO", "43", "Brown road", "Penville", "P14 5AA", "07816272182"),
    (13, "PAPERCO", "1", "Old road", "Paperville", "P34 5NA", "07111232289"),
    (24, "CALCCO", "12", "London road", "Calcville", "CA4 1XX", "07615282615"),
    (8, "BAGCO", "10", "New road", "Bagville", "BA1 1AM", "07817827131");

INSERT INTO Item VALUES
    (1, "Ballpoint pen", 1.00, "A nice pen", "~/Pictures/Pen", 20, 44),
    (2, "Notepad", 3.20, "A nice notepad", "~/Pictures/Notepad", 21, 13),
    (3, "Calculator", 4.50, "A nice calculator", "~/Pictures/Calculator", 22, 24),
    (4, "Backpack", 10.00, "A nice backpack", "~/Pictures/Backpack", 23, 8);

INSERT INTO Rep VALUES
    (41, "John", "Repman", "07019827336", 44, "JR@gmail.com", "JR@msn.com", "JRMAN", "1", "Potato street", "Patatoville", "P01 1FX"),
    (11, "Fake", "Name", "07817001992", 13, "FN@gmail.com", "FN@msn.com", "FNMAN", "3", "Fake street", "Fakeville", "FA3 9KA"),
    (1, "Good", "Name", "07911876678", 24, "GN@gmail.com", "GN@msn.com", "GNMAN", "12", "Good street", "Goodville", "GO0 1DD"),
    (666, "John", "Smith", "07918822191", 8, "JS@gmail.com", "JS@msn.com", "JSMAN", "666", "Boring street", "Boringville", "BO1 1LM");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the foregin key check with this:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

CREATE TABLES ......;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: I tried this but I got error 1452 A foreign key constraint fails when trying to add data.

Comment: can you post a sample ?

Comment: What do you mean by sample? Sample of the script?

Comment: yes, a short sample from your script that generates this error

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: sorry , there is no create of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Add the first table without foreign keys, then the second with all keys, then create the foreign key on the first table.

Comment: How do you create the foreign key afterwards?

Comment: google "Alter table" and you should find what you're looking for.